# Permissions for Resolve-PnPFolder

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am writing a script that will synchronize a folder structure (prod and an archive), but am having trouble with the Resolve-PnPFolder cmdlet.

I verified that the following works:

```
$SiteUrl = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/SalesDemo'
$RootFolder = '/Shared Documents/General'
$Credential = Get-Credential

$null = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $Credential 
$result = Add-PnPFolder -Name $Customer -Folder '/Shared Documents/General'
```

But these do not:

```
$null = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $Credential
$result = Resolve-PnPFolder -SiteRelativePath '/Shared Documents/General/Archive/$Customer/testfolder/testfolder'
```

or

```
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $Credential
Resolve-PnPFolder -SiteRelativePath '/Shared Documents/General/Archive/$Customer/testfolder/testfolder/ -Connection $connection
```

Whenever I use Resolve-PnpFolder, I get the following error:

> Resolve-PnPFolder : Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

The user in $Credential an create a folder in General and Archive, so I do not understand what is going on. I am using version 3.25.2009.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the user represented by $Credential was a member of the site. In Teams, I added the user to the owners list. After several minutes, I connected to SPO again and was able to resolve the paths.